# Missing Twig template in PhpStorm with Symfony Plugin

Tags: phpstorm, symfony

```
PhpStorm version: 9.0.2
Symfony Plugin version: 0.11.109
Symfony version: 3.0.1
```

Template referencing works fine for template files placed under `app/Resources/views` but not for files placed under `Bundle/Resources/views`.

Here goes screenshot. As you can see there is no warning highlight at first line that references to the `test.html.twig` file placed under `app/` directory, but it warns on templates that are placed under bundle resources.

Code works well and bundle templates renders in browser.

[image]

Symfony plugin configuration:

[image]

Comment: Sometime the cache is not correctly refreshed, moreover you must have generated your "dev" cache. Synchonrize / Invalidates sometimes correct the problem. (and/or restart)

Answer (score 59, accepted):

I had the same issue with `Symfony 3 / 4 / 5`. The fix is really simple.

All you have to do is add the `app/Resources/views` (or `templates` in case of `Flex`) directory manually to Twig namespaces as follows:

[image: Twig namespaces settings]

This way you can also support custom Twig namespaces, so PhpStorm can autocomplete those as well.

---

If it's not working immediately, you should invalidate the cache:

```
File -> Invalidate Caches / Restart
```

Comment: What would I have to use as project path for Craft 3? Tried with just `templates` but still getting the missing template error.

Comment: I don't know Craft3 so can't tell you where are your templates located.

Comment: No worries, I'll extract this to a dedicated question for Craft.

Comment: Note: don't fill "Namespace" like seen in the screenshot (unless you have namespaced templates), just leave it empty and PHPStorm will change it to "__ main __", otherwise PHPStorm won't be able to find your templates.

Comment: I deliberately left the popup window filled to indicate how it should be filled ;)

Answer (score 9):

I just had the same problem as well, however I didn't want to follow @Andrey Rudenko's answer because I would lose all my project specific configuration. Instead I followed @COil's comment and jusnt invalidated my cache and the problem was solved.

```
File -> Invalidate Caches / Restart -> Invailidate and Restart
```