# Missing Twig template in PhpStorm with Symfony 4 Plugin

Tags: twig, phpstorm, symfony4

```
PhpStorm version: 2018.2
Symfony Plugin Version: 0.16.165
Symfony version: 4.1.3
OS: Windows 10
```

I don't understand why, but every include and extend in my twig pages contain warning highlights about missing templates. All my twig pages are in the templates folder.

The code works, but I get complaints about them when I want to commit in git.

I've tried all answers in "[Missing Twig template in PhpStorm with Symfony Plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35148786/missing-twig-template-in-phpstorm-with-symfony-plugin)" to no avail.

[image]

Namespace has already been set.

[image]

Twig is showing correct configuration as far as I can tell.

```
$ php bin/console debug:config twig

Current configuration for extension with alias "twig"
=====================================================

twig:
    paths:
        'C:\Linux\Cygwin\home\me\PhpstormProjects\MyApp\MyApp\vendor\knplabs\knp-menu\src\Knp\Menu/Resources/views': null
        'C:\Linux\Cygwin\home\me\PhpstormProjects\MyApp\MyApp/templates': null
    debug: true
    strict_variables: true
    exception_controller: 'twig.controller.exception::showAction'
    form_themes:
        - form_div_layout.html.twig
    globals: {  }
    autoescape: name
    autoescape_service: null
    autoescape_service_method: null
    cache: 'C:\Linux\Cygwin\home\me\PhpstormProjects\MyApp\MyApp\var\cache\dev/twig'
    charset: UTF-8
    default_path: 'C:\Linux\Cygwin\home\me\PhpstormProjects\MyApp\MyApp/templates'
    date:
        format: 'F j, Y H:i'
        interval_format: '%d days'
        timezone: null
    number_format:
        decimals: 0
        decimal_point: .
        thousands_separator: ','
```

*twig.yaml*

```
twig:
    paths: ['%kernel.project_dir%/templates']
    debug: '%kernel.debug%'
    strict_variables: '%kernel.debug%'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I hadn't tried deleting the `.idea` folder because it doesn't show up in Project and assumed that Symfony 4 must have stopped using them as the question was aimed at Symfony 3.